# CodeLens no longer allowing me to show references

Tags: visual-studio, codelens

After the latest VS update (Version 17.8.0), I can no longer view references in Visual Studio through CodeLens. The option is no longer there in CodeLens either.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repairing VS made the option visible again.

Comment: Had the exact same issue, and repairing VS2022 install also fixed the problem for me!